# onMessage event is not triggered when agent sends a message amazon-connect-chatjs

Tags: javascript, angular, aws-sdk, amazon-connect

I'm integrating amazon connect chatbot on my end and I want to establish a connection between a customer and an agent. In order to so, I have used `onMessage` event to retrieve agent messages back on my platform but right now, it is not triggered.

I have initially used **aws-sdk** and **@aws-sdk/client-connectparticipant** library to send messages where I have used multiple SDKs api in this order

`startChatContact` -> `createParticipantConnection` -> `sendEvent` -> `sendMessage`

This was done in order to establish a connection between a client and an agent, so that they can send messages to each other as well. With these SDKs, I was successfully able to send messages from customer to agent but in order to retrieve the messages back, I have used `getTranscript` api inititally, which I was calling in every 2 seconds to check for any updated messages. I have also stored message ids on my end to avoid any duplicate entries.

But now I'm looking for a better solution and for that, I have used **amazon-connect-chatjs** library and I have used the code below:

```
import "amazon-connect-streams";
import "amazon-connect-chatjs";

connect.contact(contact => {
  if (contact.getType() !== connect.ContactType.CHAT) {
    // applies only to CHAT contacts
    return;
  }

  contact.onAccepted(() => {
    const cnn = contact.getConnections().find(cnn => cnn.getType() === connect.ConnectionType.AGENT);

    const agentChatSession = connect.ChatSession.create({
      chatDetails: cnn.getMediaInfo(),
      options: {
        region: "us-west-2"
      },
      type: connect.ChatSession.SessionTypes.AGENT,
      websocketManager: connect.core.getWebSocketManager()
    });
  });
});
```

I have also tried creating a customer chat session, but it is not working as well

```
const customerChatSession = connect.ChatSession.create({
  chatDetails: {
    contactId: "...",
    participantId: "...",
    participantToken: "..."
  },
  options: { // optional
    region: "us-west-2"
  },
  type: connect.ChatSession.SessionTypes.CUSTOMER
});
```

Apart from that, I have used `onTyping` event, but it is not getting triggered as well.

Please let me know if I'm missing anything or doing anything wrong here.

**Update1**

if i add `console.log`

```
const customerChatSession = connect.ChatSession.create({
  chatDetails: {
    contactId: "...",
    participantId: "...",
    participantToken: "..."
  },
  options: { // optional
    region: "us-west-2"
  },
  type: connect.ChatSession.SessionTypes.CUSTOMER
});

console.log("Here");
```

then even it does not print **Here**.

There is no error on console.

To create agentChatSession need websocket

```
connect.core.getWebSocketManager()
```

this is `undefined` even.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of the onAccepted event seems right:

```
const cnn = contact.getConnections().find(cnn => cnn.getType() === connect.ConnectionType.AGENT);

const agentChatSession = connect.ChatSession.create({
    chatDetails: cnn.getMediaInfo(), // REQUIRED
    options: { // REQUIRED
        region: "eu-central-1", // REQUIRED, must match the value provided to `connect.core.initCCP()`
    }, type: connect.ChatSession.SessionTypes.AGENT, // REQUIRED
    websocketManager: connect.core.getWebSocketManager() // REQUIRED
});
```

You will have to accept the chats using the embedded CCP. You can then react to the messages like this:

```
agentChatSession.onMessage(event => {
    // TODO react to message
})
```